# How to run g++ from a terminal window on my Mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++

I have a simple C++ program that I can compile (g++ from command line) and run from my work-computer but not from my home-computer. I don't know how they differ! They are both macbooks and I have installed iPhone SDK on both.

On my home-computer: When I add `/Developer/usr/bin` to my `PATH` I can run g++ but it cannot include `<string>` and it does not recognize `printf` and such functions. What else do I need to do to make g++ work?

Comment: How did you install gcc? Did you install the XCode tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you installed Xcode and the iPhone SDK, did you check the box for Unix Development Support? I had a lot of problems with this sort of thing because I *didn't* do that, and the solution was to uninstall the SDK and start again with the box checked.

Comment: Thanks, I don't remember if I did check that box but I will try to reinstall it.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Xcode uninstall is not 100% obvious, so you might want to see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeCoexistence/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Basics/Basics.html for details. Or just Google it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Install xCode and then close
2. Edit your c++ code file (I use Smultron, it is free and good)
3. Save your file on Desktop with "cpp" termination
4. Suppose you have test.cpp program
5. Open Terminal (Applications -> Utilities)
6. Change directory with command: cd Desktop
7. Now write: g++ test.cpp -o test
8. For run your program, in Terminal type: test (only that, **without ending cpp!**)
9. If your program it is well writen, on the desktop appear a new file named test
10. Click on it and you have your program running
11. That is all!

Comment: + 1 for command line usage. That's what I came here for. (Before I discovered that the only reason mine wasn't working was a trailing slash)